# Jquery Image vote

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using the code bellow to make a simple image voting system but i got a problem,
i want to reveal the voting result individually for each picture.

When someone press like to like button the Like div must appears only at the voted pic.

**CSS:**

```
.pborder{
width:150px;
height:247px;
border:4px solid #CCCCCC;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
z-index:1;
}

#ptitle{
width:140px;
height:18px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
background-color:#006699;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
}


#ppicdiv{
width:140xp;
height:170px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
z-index:2;
}

.fholder{
width:140px;
height:38px;
background-color:#000000;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:6px;
z-index:2;
}

.likeup{
width:28px;
height:28px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
z-index:3;
cursor:pointer;
}

.likedown{
width:28px;
height:28px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;
margin-top:5px;
z-index:3;
cursor:pointer;
}

.lvoted{
width:130px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
color: #FF0000;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:22px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:5px;
z-index:4;
background-image:url(../image/votedbg.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
display:none;
}

.dvoted{
width:130px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
color: #FF0000;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:22px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:5px;
z-index:4;
background-image:url(../image/votedbg.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
display:none;
}
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".likeup").click(function() {
$('.dvoted').hide();
$('.lvoted').show();
});

$(".likedown").click(function() {
$('.lvoted').hide();
$('.dvoted').show();
});

});
</script>
```

**Inside Body:**

```
<div class="pborder">
<div id="ptitle">Image one</div>
<div id="ppicdiv">
<div class="lvoted">Like</div>
<div class="dvoted">Dislike</div>
<img src="image/1.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="fholder">
<div class="likeup"><img src="image/like.jpg" border="0" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="likedown"><img src="image/dislike.jpg" border="0" width="28" height="28" /></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="pborder">
<div id="ptitle">Image two</div>
<div id="ppicdiv">
<div class="lvoted">Like</div>
<div class="dvoted">Dislike</div>
<img src="image/2.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="fholder">
<div class="likeup"><img src="image/like.jpg" border="0" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="likedown"><img src="image/dislike.jpg" border="0" width="28" height="28" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope to help me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please post your example in a jsfiddle, that makes it much easier to handle everbody. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".likeup").click(function() {
   $container = $(this).closest('.pborder');
   $container.find('.dvoted').hide();
   $container.find('.lvoted').show();
});

$(".likedown").click(function() {
   $container = $(this).closest('.pborder');
   $container.find('.lvoted').hide();
   $container.find('.dvoted').show();
});
```

That is, when the image is clicked navigate up through the DOM to the containing `pborder` div, and then find the `dovted` and `lvoted` items within that container only.

As an aside, your html is invalid: the `id` attribute should be unique, but you've repeated the same `id` on your `ptitle` and `ppicdiv` divs. Those should be changed to classes rather than ids, or possibly even remove the attribute from those divs altogether if you don't use it in your JS or CSS.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm Sir! and i can implement it with ajax or cookies so it can remember my vote for each picture... Am i right? Which id must be unique? Unique id for pborder?

Comment: Then i must change the id from ptitle and ppicdiv to classes and give them id's, I think if i grab the data from mysql i can have unique ids.. Am i correct?

Comment: It's fine to have unique ids, whether assigned via database identifiers or sequentially allocated or whatever. It's fine to have common classes. And it's fine for elements to have no id or class. What you need for _your_ elements depends on whether you actually need to refer to them directly in JS or CSS. That's up to you.